# Y/Y/Δ or Δ/Y/Δ transformer for a series connected 12-pulse rectifier?

Tags: power, transformer, rectifier, transmission

I'm aware that 30° shift is needed in order to obtain a 12-pulse rectification, however, I'm a bit confused about the configuration of these transformer. In most HVDC systems that appear in *[Alstom - HVDC for Beginners and Beyond](http://cigre.ru/research_commitets/ik_rus/b4_rus/library/ALSTOM_HVDC_for_Beginners_and_Beyond.pdf)*, for example, shows a WYE winding as primary:

[image]

However, I stumbled upon this similar [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_difference_between_Y_Y_D_or_D_Y_D_transformers_for_a_12_pulse_rectifier_TRU) question but it was answered as the Y/Y/Δ configuration is used and that's why I got confused.

I'm doing a simulation on PLECS in stationary state of this series connected 12-pulse rectifier so as long as I can represent leakage inductances and 30° shift it's okay as I won't do neither a transient analysis nor a fault scenario. However, I want to clarify this to at least justify why I used one configuration or the other.

Comment: The combinations you use are not important.  You need one winding that has the same in and out (Y-Y or D-D) and the other set that has a change from Y to D or the other way.

Comment: @KalleMP Thanks!. If you don't mind to clarify me something please... for these applications, Power Transformers and Converter Transformers are the same? Or does a CT include the rectifying section inside the whole 'package'?

Comment: A converter transformer is just a power transformer designed with the appropriate number of secondary windings (i.e. two LV windings for a 12-pulse converter) and designed with due regard to the harmonic load of the converter. The converter (rectifiers etc.) is supplied separately.

Answer (score 1):

A 3 winding power transformer isn't equal to a 12 pulse conver transformer. A 12 pulse transformer can have 4 windings. 2 HV and 2 LV windings. The HV and LV windings are arranged in double tier for better decoupling (still a coupling exsiting) of the winding systems and to have equal short circuit voltages.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your question is related to "why HVDC 12 pulse transformer uses Y in primary instead of a D, as converter transformer do".
Looking to the converter, it needs two secondaries with 30° shifted (1 Y and 1 D). So, your answers lies on the options for the primary windings. Converter transformers usually are connected to smalls industrial systems, that requires a D connection. HVDC transformers are connected to power systems that requires a Y connection.
Now, why the each systems needs D or Y, it's a more deep question, but I believe you can find.